# Show video with Gstreamer1.0 GTK+3.0

Tags: c++, gtk, gstreamer

I can not correctly insert a video in GtkWidget. Tell me what I'm doing wrong? The video opens in a new window, and not in the one that I'm sending. The video should open in that window on the background.

Libvlc library is displayed the same way, maybe the problem is in OS, I'm writing on Ubuntu 17.10

[App Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOKiS.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

using namespace std;


GstElement *pipeline, *src, *sink, *b;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

GtkWidget *window;
 gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  //gtk_container_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
  GdkColor color;

  gdk_color_parse ("black", &color);

  gtk_widget_modify_bg ( window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
  gtk_window_fullscreen((GtkWindow*)window);
  std::string path = std::string("file:///home/stas/eclipse-workspace/TestGTK/0.mp4");


  gst_init (&argc, &argv);




      src = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", NULL);
      sink = gst_element_factory_make ("gtksink", NULL);
      b = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "playbin");

      g_object_set(b, "uri", path.c_str());


      gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (b), src, sink, NULL);
      gst_element_link (src, sink);

      GtkWidget *area;
      g_object_get (sink, "widget", &area, NULL);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), area);

      gtk_widget_realize(area);

      gtk_widget_show_all (window);
      gst_element_set_state (b, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

      gtk_widget_show (window);

      gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you are playing a video and a videotestsrc.. It is not clear to me what you want to display where..

Comment: simple video in my GtkWidget, but gstreamer create new window and play video there

Comment: So _which_ of the two do you want to embed? Note that for playbin you should use `video-sink` property to set a sink.

Comment: I'm new to this direction, can explain in detail. I have GtkWidget area, who placed in GtkWidget  window. In the area I want play video, but video play in new window.